# Which HttpConfiguration object do I need to access to create a custom HttpParameterBinding?

Tags: http-headers, castle-windsor, global-asax, asp.net-web-api-routing, httpconfiguration

In [this post](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api), Mike Wasson states:

"*Besides ParameterBindingAttribute, there is another hook for adding a custom HttpParameterBinding. On the HttpConfiguration object*"

But I have three HttpConfiguration objects in my Web API app, namely:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config, IWindsorContainer container) <-- in WebApiConfig.cs
private static void MapRoutes(HttpConfiguration config) <-- ""
public static void ConfigureWindsor(HttpConfiguration configuration) <-- in Global.asax.cs
```

Which of these (config, config, or configuration) should I use (if any)?

### UPDATE

I tried this, with a breakpoint on the "if" line:

```
public static void ConfigureWindsor(HttpConfiguration configuration)
{
    _container = new WindsorContainer();
    _container.Install(FromAssembly.This());
    _container.Kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver(new CollectionResolver(_container.Kernel, true));
    var dependencyResolver = new WindsorDependencyResolver(_container);
    configuration.DependencyResolver = dependencyResolver;

    if (configuration.Properties.Values.Count > 0) // <-- I put a Casey Jones here
    {
        object o = configuration.Properties.Values.ElementAt(configuration.Properties.Values.Count - 1);
        string s = o.ToString();
    }
}
```

...but I only hit that spot once, on the server starting up, but not when the client sent a request to it...there must be *some* event that gets fired when a server passes a request where the incoming URL can be examined...no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you do have only one instance of HttpConfiguration which is the one you get from GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.

Said so, that's how I plugged custom binders

In global.asax

```
var binderMappings = new Dictionary<Type, Type>
    {
        {typeof(YourModelType), typeof(YourModelTypeBinder)},
        //....
    };

config.Services.Add(
    typeof(ModelBinderProvider),
    new WindsorModelBinderProvider(container, binderMappings));
```

WindsorModelBinderProvider

```
public class WindsorModelBinderProvider : ModelBinderProvider
{
    private readonly IWindsorContainer _container;
    private readonly IDictionary<Type, Type> _binderMappings;

    public WindsorModelBinderProvider(IWindsorContainer container, IDictionary<Type, Type> binderMappings)
    {
        _container = container;
        _binderMappings = binderMappings;
    }

    public override IModelBinder GetBinder(HttpConfiguration configuration, Type modelType)
    {
        IModelBinder binder = null;
        if (_binderMappings.ContainsKey(modelType))
        {
            binder = _container.Resolve(_binderMappings[modelType]) as IModelBinder;

            if (binder == null)
            {
                throw new ComponentNotFoundException(modelType);
            }
        }

        return binder;
    }
}
```

YourModelTypeBinder

```
public class YourModelTypeBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public YourModelTypeBinder(IYourServiceToLoadYourModelType service)
    {
        //...
    }

    public bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        bindingContext.Model = YourCustomCodeToLoadYourModelTypeUsingTheConstructorDependecies(actionContext.Request);
        return true;
    }

    private YourModelType YourCustomCodeToLoadYourModelTypeUsingTheConstructorDependecies(HttpRequestMessage requestMessage)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

YourModelTypeBinder will be resolved by the container(see WindsorModelBinderProvider), so you need to registered it first.

After all that plumbing, your controller may have a parameter, among others, as following

```
[ModelBinder]YourModelType user
```